# Can we have both upsampling and downsampling layers in an Encoder/Decoder?

Tags: autoencoder

I am new to auto-encoders. All the autoencoders that i have seen usually exhibit a downsampling encoder followed by an upsampling decoder or an upsampling encoder followed by a down sampling decoder.
Now, i want to ask, can we have an encoder that contains both upsampling and downsampling layers simultaneously, followed by a decoder having exact mirrored layers of the encoder??
For example can we have the following architecture of autoencoder?

**Encoder:** 16 neurons - 200 neurons - 400 neurons - 200 neurons - **4 neurons (latent representation)** - **Decoder:** 200 neurons - 400 neurons - 200 neurons - 16 neurons

Is this a valid autoencoder? or is it a simple tandem neural network ?

Answer (score 1):

I would still consider this architecture as an autoencoder, given it is trained as such. There is no formal definition for the requirements of the layer sizes, other than that input and output have to be of the same dimensionality. You can also build "overcomplete" autoencoders, where the dimensionality of your latent space is bigger than the dimensionality of your input.

As long as you are using it as an autoencoder, meaning you train with input data `x` to generate an output `x'` while penalizing with something like `L = ||x-x'||²`, the architecture of the layers are pretty much arbitrary.

Whether it makes sense to have different upscaling and downscaling in both en- and decoding is another issue.